# Implement retry & skip policy callback with SpringBatch 5

Tags: spring-batch

I have implemented a Step using SpringBatch. I have a basic project which aims to import a CSV into a MySQL database.

I want to be able to handle possible issues:

1. If the content is not valid
2. if we have connexion issue with MySQL

For this in Step I can implement retries :

```
@Bean
public Step step1(
        BatchReadListener listener,
        JobRepository jobRepository,
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager,
        RepositoryItemWriter<EstablishmentEntity> writer) throws IOException {
    log.warn("step() called");
    return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
            .<EstablishmentEntity, EstablishmentEntity> chunk(10, transactionManager)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer)
            .listener(listener)
            .faultTolerant()
            .retryLimit(128)
            .retry(PessimisticLockException.class)
            .retry(PessimisticLockingFailureException.class)
            .retry(CannotAcquireLockException.class)
            .retry(SQLException.class)
            //.retry(DeadlockLoserDataAccessException.class)
            .build();
}
```

How can i store failures and do retry in the end of process ?

Answer (score 0):

Transient issues (like flaky network calls) can be addressed with a retry policy. Persistent issues (like incorrect content in a file) should be addressed with a skip policy.

So in your case:

> 1. If the content is not valid

The content could be validated in the item processor. Invalid items could be skipped by using a `SkipListener#onSkipInProcess`.

> 2. if we have connexion issue with MySQL

This can be retried. The exceptions shared in the code seem to be retriable.